# Ruby Threading: rb_thread_blocking_region()?

Tags: ruby

i am using Ruby + GTK with threads.

I have one question on RUBY-THREADING

Is there is any way to run long running threads that does not blocks UI. 
i searched a lot, all of my searches end's with this function **rb_thread_blocking_region**

But there is no clear documentation about "rb_thread_blocking_region" .

How can i achieve real threading in RUBY....

Thanks in advance.